# How to return two values in C

Tags: c

I have the following function:

```
int conMS(time_in_seconds) {
  int minutes, seconds;
  minutes = time_in_seconds / 60;
  seconds = time_in_seconds % 60;
  return minutes, seconds;
}
```

When used in another function, I get several error messages:

```
warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
 minutes,seconds = conMS(time);
warning: ‘minutes’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
 return minutes, seconds;
```

Anyways, is there a way where one can return two values from a function. Those two values could by anything: an `int` and a `char`, a `float` and an `int`...

I'm sorry if this is a no-brainer for you,but I'm a beginner in C and the only way I can learn is by asking questions. Also please make your explanation as simple as possible.

**Update:** This can be easily done through pointers as follow.

```
void conMS(int time, 
int *minutesP, /* a pointer to variable minutes */
int *secondsP) // a pointer to variable seconds //
{ 
    *minutesP = time / 60; 
    *secondsP = time % 60; 
}
```

Later on you would call this function as:

```
conMS( 210, &minutes, &secs)    /* Where minutes, secs are defined integers */
```

And this would assign the time in seconds to the variable `minutes` and assign seconds to the variable `secs`

Comment: hint: either pass 2 pointers or create a struct

Comment: `return minutes * bias + seconds;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY. very clever. I'd use a 6 bit left shift instead (since seconds will always be less than 60). It's clearer IMO.

Comment: Here `Time conMS(time_in_seconds)` the argument `time_in_seconds` misses the type. And everybody copied it ... :-)

Comment: Seconds less that 60? Don't forget the bane of scientific programming: leap seconds.

Comment: @Bathsheba, still fits in 6 bits :)

Comment: @StoryTeller Luckily. But I do die a little inside every time I read "will always be less than 60".

Comment: @Bathsheba, the example in the OP can be nothing else. Besides, magnitude constraints are the basis for packing values into integers.

Comment: @Bathsheba `seconds = time_in_seconds % 60;`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Two choices:

1) Pass pointers to the variables that will be modified. Your function prototype then becomes

```
int conMS(time_in_seconds, int* minutes, int* seconds)
```

2) Use a `struct` containing `minutes` and `seconds` as members and return that.

I prefer (1) as in the case of (2) I'm always anxious about taking unnecessary value copies and I get nervous when relying on *return value optimisation* as that's essentially a compiler choice and not mandated by standard C. Also, the caller syntax `comMS(time_in_seconds, &minutes, &seconds)` tells me to *expect* `minutes` and `seconds` to be modified.

Some convention has also grown with option (1): a zero result normally indicates success, non-zero for failure.

Comment: Note: it is usual to return an error code (or a success code) in the first case.

Comment: @Stasik: that's a good point; I've incorporated into this answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can create struct and return it

```
struct time{
   int minutes;
   int seconds;
};

struct time conMS(time_in_seconds)
{
   struct time ret;
   ret.minutes = time_in_seconds / 60;
   ret.seconds = time_in_seconds % 60;
   return ret;
}
```

Comment: +1 for supplying the correct code, but do note that this, conceptually, does take a deep copy of the entire structure when the function returns.

Answer (score 8):

You can use pointers..

```
void conMS(int time_in_seconds, int * minutes, int * seconds)
{
    *minutes = time_in_seconds / 60;
    *seconds = time_in_seconds % 60;
}
```

You can call it like this...

```
int time = 187;
int m, s;

conMS(time, &m, &s);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not `return` 2 values from a function at a time.
You can put these values in a structure and `return` the structure as shown below:

```
typedef struct time
{
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
}Time;

Time conMS(int time_in_seconds)
{
    Time t;
    t.minutes = time_in_seconds / 60;
    t.seconds = time_in_seconds % 60;
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but as I said earlier I'm a newbie so I don't really know what a structure is.For now isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: @Andy: you need to *learn* what a structure is. It's a very important part of C.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'm doing that right now.Thank you all for your great answers.If I could only pick all of you as best answers, I would. But I cant.

Answer (score 3):

Use a struct to contain minutes and seconds and return the struct.

```
struct time{
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
};

struct time conMS(time_in_seconds)
{
    struct time t;
    int minutes, seconds;
    minutes = time_in_seconds / 60;
    seconds = time_in_seconds % 60;

    t.minutes = minutes;
    t.seconds = seconds;

    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

declare a structure with variables as per your requirement and return a object of that structure.

```
struct name
{
   int  minutes;    
   int  seconds;
};

struct name conMS(time_in_seconds)
{
   struct name obj;        /*structure object which contains both*/ 
   obj.minutes = time_in_seconds / 60;
   obj.seconds = time_in_seconds % 60;
   return obj;
}


main()
{
    struct name obj = canMS(60);
    printf( " %d   %d \n", obj.minutes, obj.seconds ) ;
}
```

obj.minutes & obj.seconds are your variables.

Comment: How is this different than the other 4 answers that offer the same solution?

Comment: its same... I have written it earlier while no answer were there and posted it after time. meanwhile there are so many answers and everybody will say the same thing for that question

Comment: Exactly. If somebody else beat you to the punch, it's good practice to remove your now redundant answer and clear up space and clutter on the page. There will be plenty of other opportunities to give great answers without redundancy.